# Problem in Convert mm/dd/yyyy To dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion, varchar

I need to have same result for these two queries with format: 'dd/mm/yyyy

what should I do?

```sql
DECLARE @Date varchar(10) = '01/02/1958'

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date, 103) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONVERT(Date, @Date, 103) 
        ELSE TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date) 
    END

DECLARE @Date2 Date = '01/02/1958'

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date2, 103) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONVERT(Date, @Date2, 103) 
        ELSE TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date2) 
    END
```

Comment: Why you store dates as string at all? ALWAYS store them as datetime/date.

Comment: If you *are* using string literals for dates (such as when assigning a value to a variable). use an unambiguous format, such as `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: Also `TRY_CONVERT (Date,@Date2,103)` isn't going to do anything; you are converting the variable `@Date`, which is the `date` datatype, to a `date`; the style code is for when converting to or from a string based data type (`(n)(var)char`) to a **different** data type. You're converting from a `date` to a `date`, so the style parameter will be (effectively) ignored.

Comment: I need to have both result even varchar or date like 1958-02-01, but second query returns 1958-01-02 when consider as a date. these variable comes from different sources and sometimes was date and sometimes varchar! What's your idea to handle this issue in this situation?

Comment: Don't store dates in strings. But to get the same result from both queries have you tried `SET DATEFORMAT DMY;` yet?

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary types. Use `date` as the type so you don't have to worry about formats. `declare @date date='1958-01-02'` or `declare @date date='19580102'`. To display that binary value a certain way use either `CONVERT` or `FORMAT` with the desired format.

Comment: In truth, the format the dates are *displayed* should be defined in the *display* layer, not the SQL. Don't `CONVERT`/`FORMAT` the dates in SQL, pass your application a strongly typed date (and time) value, and then *it* can use that (binary) value to display that date (and time) value in the desired format, which might be based on the user location data, personal settings, etc

Comment: Basically, I need to handle both formats in one query result.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I didn't get your idea.

Comment: Then how do *you* know what date `01/02/1958` is? Is it 01 Feburary 1958 or 02 Janurary 1958? And, more importantly, how does SQL Server know?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
I do, but the results are different. It should be in one query and handle by Case/When for example.

Comment: @Larnu
I want to first try for 01 February and then try for 02 January. the preferred format is dd/mm/yyyy for dates like '30/12/1990'

Comment: So `ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(date,YourVarcharValue,103),TRY_CONVERT(date,YourVarcharValuee,101))`? personally, however, I still **strongly** suggest using an unambiguous format.

Comment: @ArefAlizadeh the results are not different precisely because `date` is a binary value. What changes is how that same binary value is displayed. The same binary date value will appear differently in SSMS running in one locale and a desktop application running in a different locale. Just try `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @date, 101)` and `SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @date, 103)`. Or ``SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GETDATE(), 5)`

Comment: @Larnu

but queries have different result unfortunately. but maybe I can use format 101

Comment: *"but queries have different result unfortunately"* I have no idea what you mean by this. The real answer remains the same; stop using ambiguous format.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 2 types of date in your strings, when you write `DECLARE @Date2 Date = '01/02/1958'`, you are saying 'I whant to convert that string in a date based on my server configuration'.
With that :

```
DECLARE @Date varchar(10) = '01/02/1958'

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date, 103) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONVERT(Date, @Date, 103) 
        ELSE TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date) 
    END

DECLARE @Date2 Date = '01/02/1958'
SET @Date2 = CONVERT(Date,(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Date2,101)),103);

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date2, 103) IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONVERT(Date, @Date2, 103) 
        ELSE TRY_CONVERT(Date, @Date2) 
    END
```

I'm saying 'Ok, convert the `@Date2` from US to EU convention. When manipulating Date formats, be sure to always cast your string with a correct format